# Pass complex, non-primitive data types to Terraform template provider

Tags: terraform

Having a more complex list object like this

```
variable "proxy" {
  type = list(object({
    enabled = bool
    host = string
    port = number
    user = string
    password = string
  }))
  default = [
    {
      enabled = false
      host = ""
      port = 0
      user = ""
      password = ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to use this in a external template (cloudinit in my case). The [`template_file` directive](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html) allows passing variables to a template. Sadly, not for more complex types:

> Note that variables must all be primitives. Direct references to lists or maps will cause a validation error.

So something like this

```
data "template_file" "cloudinit_data" {
  template = file("cloudinit.cfg")
  vars = {
    proxy = var.proxy
  }
}
```

cause the error

> Inappropriate value for attribute "vars": element "proxy": string required.

This leads me to two questions:

1. How can I pass the variable to the template? I assume that I need to convert it to a primitive type like this:

   ```
   vars = {
       proxy_host = var.proxy.host
   }
   ```

This doesn't work:

> This value does not have any attributes.

2. Is there an alternative way to pass this object directly to the template?

I'm using v0.12.17.

Comment: The template renderer probably does not support this yet, so you would have to do it within the Terraform DSL. Then it is certainly possible to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: And how can I access the proxy variable to pass its element as single variables to the template?

Comment: I tried to find the documentation for that, but it seems difficult to google. You would be doing something like `var.proxy[0]["host"]` to access the value of the `host` key at the `0th` element of the array.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I don't need an array, so I changed `type = list(object({` to `type = object({`. It works but just after I removed the `default` value definition (also without the array brackets `[]`). With default value, I got _Invalid expression Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token_ error. Is it not possible to define a default value for just objects, that were not part of an array?

Comment: It sounds like a syntax issue, but I can try to reproduce this later myself.

Answer (score 2):

The `template_file` data source continues to exist only for compatibility with configurations written for Terraform 0.11. Since you are using Terraform 0.12, you should use [the `templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) instead, which is a built-in part of the language and supports all value types.

Because `templatefile` is a function, you can call it from anywhere expressions are expected. If you want to use the rendered result multiple times then you could define it as a [named local value](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html), for example:

```
locals {
  cloudinit_data = templatefile("${path.module}/cloudinit.cfg", {
    proxy = var.proxy
  })
}
```

If you only need this result once -- for example, if you're using it just to populate the `user_data` of a single `aws_instance` resource -- then you can just write this expression inline in the resource block, to keep everything together and make the configuration (subjectively) easier to read:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # ...

  user_data = templatefile("${path.module}/cloudinit.cfg", {
    proxy = var.proxy
  })
}
```

Comment: Really helpful for someone like me, who was mistaking the data source for the function and wondering why it won't work.